# Activity Related List doesn't have Sort Option

Tags: related-list

There is no option on the activity list to sort by subject or other field but it is showing on all other object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to sort

Check this URL
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gjWXAAY